# How to sign an application bundle with the same display name as the installer package?

Tags: macos, install, keychain, certificate, package-management

I can sign a bundle with "Mac Developer" identity which is connected to my Apple account user name (ie a "person").
I can sign the package (.pkg) that contains the bundle with a "3rd Party Mac Developer Installer" identity (ie an "organization").

This results in the signature on the package (the organization) being different than the signature on the component (the developer that built the component).

It seems the "Mac Developer" name is hard linked to the Apple developer account and it is not possible to slide in the organization name instead.

How to sign components (applications, executables) with an organization name instead of a human person name?

Comment: Where did you get the installer certificate from? Having different certificate common names suggests the **Mac Developer** and **3rd Party Mac Developer Installer** were issued to different Apple Developer IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple needs to issue a new certificate with the desired organisation name. This typically requires the organisation to have an Apple Developer ID.

1. Connect to the [Developer Account](https://developer.apple.com/account) for the **organisation**;
2. Select [Certificates](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/list)
3. Add a [New Certificate](https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/add), then either:

   - Select **Developer ID Installer** for distribution outside of the Mac App Store;
   - Select **Mac Installer Distribution** for submission to the Mac App Store.
4. Select **Continue** and complete the remaining steps.

Comment: Good clues - thanks!  The solution in the end for creating a mac installer (.pkg) containing mac executables for distribution _outside_ the mac store was to generate two certificates ("Developer ID Application" and "Developer ID Installer") by the Apple Developer Account holder (owner).  Any certs created by members (but not the owner) were essentially useless.  Transfer the owner certificates to the developer machine in .p12 format along with a separate password.

Comment: Also, submitting the .pkg using the Apple **notarytool** was incredible useful as it would give a detailed report (log) of any signing errors.